# Add space after full stops

Tags: python, regex, replace, text-processing

What is the clean way in python to do this simple text fixing - checking if every full stop (except the last one) is followed by space. Assume that having a dot not followed by an empty space is the only possible error we can get in the input string.

I am doing this:

```
def textFix(text):
    result = re.sub('\.(?!\s)', '. ', text)
    if (result[len(result) - 1]) == ' ':
        return result[:-1]
    return result
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may check it with

```
\.(?!\s|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPkBJI/1). It matches a dot not followed with whitespace or end of string, that is, any non-final dot that has no whitespace after it.

Or, you may also consider

```
\.(?=\S)
```

to match any dot followed with a non-whitespace char.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPkBJI/2).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/aiEDsq):

```
import re
rx = r"\.(?=\S)"
s = "Text1. Text2.Text3."
result = re.sub(rx, ". ", s)
print(result)
# => "Text1. Text2. Text3."
```

Comment: BTW, the `\.(?=\S)` is preferable since it works faster due to no alternation present in the lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if the sentence contains a decimal value like 98.6

Comment: @MadhurYadav There are several approaches, you may use `re.sub(r"\.(?!(?<=\d\.)\d)(?=\S)", ". ", s)`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/4NQMRE).

Answer (score 1):

Your technique looks perfect. But also include a check to avoid adding space after last dot (`.`)

```
\.(?!\s)(?!$)
```

where `(?!$)` helps make sure if the `.` is followed by end of string `$` then isn't matched and so no space is added after it.

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VS3mAE/1/)